Ideas for Supporting this Joist
I have an unfinished basement and noticed this joist not supported like all the others.  Need some ideas how to fix this.  See photo.
This is the "Good" truss

This is the stubby truss.  Looks like some kind of double top on this one.


Probably no fixing is needed. Those metal plates are used quite a lot and a very good chance it was designed and inspected that way, instead of it being an oops.

@crip659 Thoae metal plates are non structural. My floor above is going to sag eventually.

Worst case, you stack a couple of 2x4s or a 4x4 under it and box out the surrounding drywall.

@Huesmann I showed this Pic to the builder and they said they would add some blocking. Not sure how they plan to do it but at least they see a need for it. Thanks

@RickS, look into the Dunning-Kruger effect. You don't know what you think you know. Your first comment is flat wrong. There's no problem here.

Not sure why you think the metal plates are non structural. Plates just like that have been holding my garage roof trusses together for > 30 years. Despite the overloaded bottom chord, they're showing no signs of sagging...

@FreeMan They look like these from Lowes.  Says non structural
https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Pack-6-in-x-3-in-x-Plate/3047922

They're non-structural when you buy them at your home improvement store and mash them onto your project with a hammer. They're certainly structural when that's all there is holding an entire engineered joist together, and they were installed with specialized equipment in a controlled manner. Did you miss that part of the big picture? How could they not be structural?

@isherwood. Got it. We've had issues with this builder cutting corners. Just want to make sure it's done right and safe.

You're right--it's not supported like the other ones. That doesn't mean there's a problem.
This is a top-hanging joist, which is very common in engineered floors. Sometimes all the joists hang like that on a beam, foundation wall, ledger, etc. Leave it alone and don't gunk up your basement with weird blocking out of misperception and paranoia. I see at least one toenail at the bottom, so there shouldn't be much lateral movement.
It would also be inappropriate to drop jack studs under it. Unless they're supported by footings (not just the floor slab) they'd be both pointless and a code violation. Even with a footing, this isn't intended to be a load point.

Going to vote for this one.  Maybe it's the new photos but the first glance is... just designed this way to accommodate the other parts of the frame.

The "joist"  floor truss to the right looks like it is sitting on the framed wall. (purple mark).
Is the unsupported truss moveable?  Can it be pulled down and anchored to the top of the wall?  (blue marks)
One would think the floor trusses should run in the same plane. Is there something else going on here?  If so you could block between the bottom of the truss and the top of the wall. A proper fitting joist hanger, (as shown at the green arrow), could be used as well.
What needs to be done depends on how movable the truss is and what reaction occurs if it is moved.  A 2x4 nailed to the top of the wall and into the truss is simple but could work.  It really depends on how much deflection there is with the truss.  If it is just a matter that it isn't fully supported on the bottom, but it doesn't move, a block nailed in at the bottom, will work.  If there is more lateral movement then blocking between adjacent trusses is needed.


Thanks for the reply. The builder agreed to add blocking.  Any suggestions on how to best block it?

Add to my answer above.  My query is still why the truss is at a different level than the adjacent one.

No clue why that truss is different. Had two friends comment that it needs some support. Either a hanger or one suggested building a wall under it.

@RMDman what do you mean by "different level?"  They all look to be the same level to me.  Same length?  No.  The other weird thing is that shorty truss that the joist in question butts up to.

@Huesmann,  To me it looks like the truss in the middle, (the one in question) has the bottom about 1 1/2 " above the wall top plate. Whereas the truss on the right sit on the wall.  Optical illusion?   The OPs original pic shows what I'm seeing better.

It looks to me like there is a little piece above the wall plate running to the left.  That blocks the middle truss from going over the wall plate.  The trusses are at the same level, but there's that piece a level above the wall plate running to the left.  If it's an optical illusion, it's fooling me too.  I'm not sure it can move to the right, as I think the blockage might still be there (I think it blocks the width of the truss, not just the width of the empty spot).  We'd need a different angle to see beyond the end of the truss on the right.

@RMDman looks to me like there's a 4-stack of (jack? king?) studs that supports a double top plate, the end of which is flush with that stack.  Looks to me like all the joists are even (flush?) with the top of the top plate, including that shorty joist that's perpendicular to the joist in question.

@RMDman I added a few more pics to the post.

This answer is chock full of assumptions and speculation (not to mention questions). It's misleading at best. There is no unsupported truss here.
